# How to intercept HttpsUrlConnection#connect prior to encryption in order to debug request created

Tags: java, encryption, https

I currently need to write some client sending Https requests to some server. As you might know it is not that easy to debug such scenarios. Especially since I do not have access to the server and thus I am unable to sniff the network traffic.

What I would like to do for debugging purposes within my java program is intercept the request formed by the HttpsUrlConnection object prior to encryption and print it to the console. That way I would be able to see exactly what I am sending.

Does someone know of a way to achieve this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the source code that calls HttpsUrlConnection?

Comment: Yes. I have complete control over the client. It is my own program.

Comment: [Classic XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862) It would make more sense to describe the actual problem you're trying to debug, rather than invent a debugging facility that doesn't exist and ask how to implement it so you can debug the problem you're trying to debug.

Comment: Sorry for not satisfying your high standards. The problem is that I am sending an HTTPS request to a server where I need to be authenticated. I believe I've built the request correctly but the server always returns a 401 NOT AUTHENTICATED. Unfortunately I can not get server logs or something similar so I would like to see the actual request that is send before it is encrypted.